# ManagedBean method called on XHTML page opening

Tags: jsf, javabeans

I'm developping with Eclise Juno, Tomcat 7 and JSF.

When I run my project on Server, it seems that Client.fct1() method is ran. This is setting values in my XHTML InputText.

Upon startup I expect to see only the values set from my Bean Constructor method.

Here is my XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="./template.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="onLoadJS" value="initialize()" />
    <ui:define name="top">
        Frontend
        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="#{utils.GMapURL}">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var map;

            function initialize() {
                var x = 500;
                document.getElementById("bottom").style.height = x+'px'; 
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.84325, 2.237803),
                    zoom: 14,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("bottom"),
                mapOptions);
                google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                                                                addPlacemark(event.latLng.lat(),event.latLng.lng());
                                                            });
            }

            function add(vlat,vlon,vname) {
                ...
            }

            function addPlacemark(vlat,vlon) {
                ...
            }

            function lookAt(vlat,vlon) {
                ...
            }

            function resetBean() {
                alert("ResetBean!");
                #{client.fct1()};
            }

        </script>

        <A HREF="faces/map.xhtml">Placemark</A> <A HREF="faces/directions.xhtml">Directions</A> 
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="body">
        <h4>Latitude  : <h:inputText id="lat" value="#{client.lat}"/></h4>
        <h4>Longitude : <h:inputText id="lon" value="#{client.lon}"/></h4>
        <h4>Name      : <h:inputText id="name" value="#{client.name}"/></h4>
    <h:commandButton onclick="add(document.getElementById('lat').value,document.getElementById('lon').value,document.getElementById('name').value)" value="Add"/>
    <h:commandButton onclick="lookAt(document.getElementById('lat').value,document.getElementById('lon').value)" value="Look At"/>
    <h:commandButton onclick="displayAll()" value="Display All"/>
    <h:commandButton onclick="resetBean()" value="Reset Form (bean)"/>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="bottom">
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

And my bean:

```
package web;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class Client
 */
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Client implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String lat;
private String lon;
private String name;

// Constructor
public Client() {
    this.lat = "11.2051195";
    this.lon = "119.4056492";
    this.name = "[Put name here]";
}

public void fct1(){
    this.lat = "Damn";
    this.lon = "It";
    this.name = "..";
}

public String getLat() {
    return lat;
}

public void setLat(String lat) {
    this.lat = lat;
}

public String getLon() {
    return lon;
}

public void setLon(String lon) {
    this.lon = lon;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

So I am getting "Damn It ..." instead of the default "11.2051195 119.4056492 [Put name here]".

How come the fct1() method is called?
How can I prevent it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You seem toassume that in

```
        function resetBean() {
            alert("ResetBean!");
            #{client.fct1()};
        }
```

The `#{client.fct1()};` is called when the javascript function `resetBean()` is called. It is not. It is executed when the page is rendered (so no onload) since it is not in any jsf tag. If you want to call a remote method from javascript, the easiest thing to use is the [OmniFaces commandScript](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/commandScript) (using omnifaces in your project is a good idea anyway)

Your code would then look like

```
        function resetBean() {
            alert("ResetBean!");
            callFct1();
        }
```

And in you xhtml add

```
<o:commandScript name="callFct1" action="#{client.fct1()}">
```